# Calculation of age of domain by passing value in URL using POST method

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to calculate the domain age of several website from http://www.webconfs.com/domain-age.php by passing the variable in the URL like http://www.webconfs.com/domain-age.php?domains=youtube.com.

The problem is in `form` tag of this site, they are using `POST` method, so in my Python code, whether I append the domain name or not returns the same web page.

How can I pass the value of a different website from the URL and the result web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for making a [`POST` request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=post#requests.post) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) HTML parser for getting the age form the html page:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://www.webconfs.com/domain-age.php"
>>> domain = 'youtube.com' 
>>> r = requests.post(url, {'domains': domain, 'submit': 'submit'})
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> for item in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('website-history')):
...     print item.text
... 
9 years 0 months old
```